# EFDesigner Load Nuget Packages object reference is not set to an instance of an object

Tags: ef-core-2.1

I've downloaded **Entity Framework Visual Editor** visual studio extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michaelsawczyn.EFDesigner

Started new project in Visual Studio  **.NET Core Class Library**

Clicked **Add New Item** -> **EFDesigner**

Right Clicked on blank area and clicked **"Load Nuget Packages"**

Receive exception

[image]

Visual Studio Version 15.8.2
.NET Core 2.1

Any ideas how to fix?